# Mapping Unique Key to Foreign Key in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a one to many relation like this:
Person(personID: PK) is the Abstract class
Employee(employeeId: PK, vetId: FK) extends Person with many to one
Vet(vetID: UK(unique key))

I've created a BaseEntity and mapped it as supper class.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(length = 36, columnDefinition = "varchar(36)", updatable = false, nullable = false )
    private UUID id;
    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }
}
```

the abstract table extends from base Class. In my SQL schema I will have this abstract table, therefore I marked it as @Entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@Entity
public abstract class Person extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String alias;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String gender; //should be refactored to point to an Enum
}
```

the employee extends Person. I make employee an Entity as I will have a table called employee

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate employmentDate;
    private Double salary;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=VeterinaryDoctor.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vetID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<VeterinaryDoctor> veterinaryDoctors;
}
```

the employee can have multiple vets. I make Vet an Entity as I will have a table

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Vet extends Employee implements Serializable {

    @Column(unique=true)
    private UUID veterinaryRegistryId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate qualificationDate;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('CARDIOLOGY', 'DENTISTRY', 'NUTRITIONIST')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Speciality speciality;
}
```

I have an enum for the vet speciality, which I wire in the vet class

```
public enum Speciality {
    CARDIOLOGY,
    DENTISTRY,
    NUTRITIONIST
}
```

How should I define my Vet so that vetId from Vet table which is a UK points to the vetId from Employee table which is a FK.
I need to understand the pattern so I can carry on and define other employees.
I think it has to do with constraints?

**Update1:**
changing

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

to

```
@JoinColumn(name = "vetID", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

**Update2**
to have **vetId** as UK I am updating

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Id
private UUID vetId;
```

to

```
@Column(unique=true)
private UUID veterinaryRegistryId;
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Your implementation seems good. what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am not sure if it is. It doesn't seem right to me. 
Shouldn't this be 
@JoinColumn(name = "vetID", referencedColumnName = "id") ?
should I have this annotation as well?
@Column(unique = true) ?

how can I differentiate from a FK to a UK mapping?

In my instance i have UK to FK, but it seams more like PK to FK?

Comment: you have marked  `@Id private UUID vetId` . This alone marks it as primary key. A primary key is also a unique key. You need the following however `@JoinColumn(name = "vetID", referencedColumnName = "id")`

Comment: Unique Key (UK): It's a column or a group of columns that can identify a uniqueness in a row. ... PK creates a Clustered index and UK creates a Non Clustered Index. PK is not null, but UK allows nulls (Note: By Default) There can only be one and only one PK on a table, but there can be multiple UK's

should I remove the @Id annotation? if Uk can be null, how can I make it accept null values? I am updating the post

Comment: you can remove `@Id` if you don't want it to be primary key. Then you can add `Column(unique=true)` But all this concept seems wrong to me. Your primary key will also behave as a unique key.

Comment: the ideea is that vetId might be missing, therefore that is why it is a UK. a UK allows null

Comment: But a Vet represents a table in the database. How can other columns exist and the id of the Vet be null? Tables without primary keys are always dangerous. But if that's what you need go for it

Comment: it is my requirements. It is a good question that I can ask. I am new to `SQL` and finding my ways.
It is dangerous, but what if the system data is old. sometimes, id's are missing.

So, if I'd want to make it `UK`, I can remove the `@Id` and add `Column(unique=true)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230612/discussion-between-scilla-and-boug).